# Covert jQuery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is my code please covert my jQuery into javascript.**
**Convert in javascript**

```
$(".wrapper td li>span").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace(".", ""); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `querySelectorAll` and `textContent`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function(el) {
  el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/\./g, '')
});
```

```html
<span>1. abc</span><br/>
<span>2. def</span>
```

Comment: @Sawanmishra Place [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) before the code

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll' . Please make code for enterprise mode

Comment: Finally I got a proper answer to convert jQuery to JavaScript with and issues on enterprise mode of internet explorer

var spans=document.body.querySelectorAll('.wrapper td li>span')
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
spans[i].innerText = spans[i].innerText.replace(/\./g, '')
}

Comment: Could you please explain what doesn't work with the polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill

Comment: querySelectorAll need to master tag and in polyfill not example seen

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I got a proper answer to convert jQuery to JavaScript with and issues on enterprise mode of internet explorer**

```
var spans=document.body.querySelectorAll('.wrapper td li>span')
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
spans[i].innerText = spans[i].innerText.replace(/\./g, '')
}
```